# Java convert unix timestamp to wrong time

Tags: java, unix, unix-timestamp

I have unix timestammp stored in mysql. I am converting it into time. It displays wrong time.

Here is code:

```
Date date = new Date((long)timestamp*1000); 
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm a"); 
sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT+5:30"));
timeString = sdf.format(date);
System.out.println(timeString);`
```

`timestamp` is variable which contains unix timestamp.
Ex: for `timestamp=1417437428505` it should show 6:07 PM and showing 12:31 AM

What is solution for it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're multiplying a timestamp which is *already* in milliseconds since the Unix epoch by 1000. You just want:

```
Date date = new Date(timestamp);
```

If you look at all of the date, not just the time, you'll see it's currently in 46886!

Answer (score 1):

Are You sure that need multiplied by 1000? I tried pass without multiplying `Date date = new Date(timestamp);` and it printed 6:07 PM

Answer (score 0):

Remove multiply with 1000 in

Date date = new Date((long)timestamp*1000);

than it works.